# PHP Script wont load table with large amount of data

Tags: php, mysqli

I would first like to start by saying I don't know a hole lot about PHP, so I had purchased a User Management script to help manage my site.

Im imported all my users into the script which is 5400+ accounts, in the users management section of the script when i click to view users the script will time out with Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in users.php on line 45. I've tried adding ini_set("max_execution_time", "0"); to the beginning of the script but then it will just spin for 3-5 mins and Apache will time out. This is on my web server and local host.

Below is line 42 through 48

```
function get_user_meta($account_id, $term) { 
    global $db;
    $query = "SELECT * from user_meta WHERE account_id='".$account_id."'";
    $result = $db->query($query) or die($db->error);
    $row = $result->fetch_array();
    return $row[$term];
}//get user email ends here
```

And the section of the code that list users is.

```
function list_users($user_type) {
    global $db;
    global $language;
    if($user_type == 'admin') { 
        $query = 'SELECT * from users ORDER by account_id ASC';     
        $result = $db->query($query) or die($db->error);
        $content = '';
        $count = 0;
        while($row = $result->fetch_array()) { 
            extract($row);
            $count++;
            if($count%2 == 0) { 
                $class = 'even';
            } else { 
                $class = 'odd';
            }
            $content .= '<tr class="'.$class.'">';
            $content .= '<td>';
            $content .= $first_name.' '.$last_name;
            $content .= '</td><td>';
            if($city != '') { 
            $content .= $city.', ';
            }
            if($state != '') { 
            $content .= $state.', ';
            }
            $content .= $country;
            $content .= '</td><td>';
            $content .= $username;
            $content .= '</td><td>';
            $content .= $email;
            $content .= '</td><td>';
            $content .= ucfirst($status);
            $content .= '</td><td>';
            $content .= ucfirst($user_type);
            $content .= '</td><td>';
            $content .= $this->get_user_meta($account_id, 'last_login_time');
            $content .= '</td><td>';
            $content .= $this->get_user_meta($account_id, 'last_login_ip');
            $content .= '</td><td>';
            $content .= '<button class="btn btn-default btn-sm pull-left" style="margin-right:5px;" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal_'.$account_id.'">'.$language["message"].'</button>';
            $content .= '<!-- Modal -->
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
$("#message_form_'.$account_id.'").on("submit", function(e){
e.preventDefault();
tinyMCE.triggerSave();
$.post("includes/messageprocess.php", 
 $("#message_form_'.$account_id.'").serialize(), 
 function(data, status, xhr){
   $("#success_message_'.$account_id.'").html("<div class=\'alert alert-success\'>"+data+"</div>");
 });
});
});
</script>               
<div class="modal fade" id="modal_'.$account_id.'" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
<form id="message_form_'.$account_id.'" method="post" name="send_message">
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">'.$language["send_message"].'</h4>
  </div>

  <div class="modal-body">
        <div id="success_message_'.$account_id.'"></div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">'.$language["message_to"].'</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="message_to" value="Email:('.$email.') Username: ('.$username.')" readonly="readonly" />
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">'.$language["subject"].'</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="subject" value="" />
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">'.$language["message"].'</label>
            <textarea class="tinyst form-control" name="message"></textarea>
        </div>
  </div>
  <input type="hidden" name="from" value="'.$_SESSION['account_id'].'" />
  <input type="hidden" name="account_id" value="'.$account_id.'" />
  <input type="hidden" name="single_form" value="1" />
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">'.$language["close"].'</button>
    <input type="submit" value="Send Message" class="btn btn-primary" />
  </div>
</div><!-- /.modal-content -->
</form>
</div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->';            
            $content .= '<form method="post" name="edit" action="manage_users.php">';
            $content .= '<input type="hidden" name="edit_user" value="'.$account_id.'">';
            $content .= '<input type="submit" style="margin-right:5px;" class="btn btn-default btn-sm pull-left" value="'.$language["edit"].'">';
            $content .= '</form>';
            $content .= '<form method="post" name="delete" onsubmit="return confirm_delete();" action="">';
            $content .= '<input type="hidden" name="delete_user" value="'.$account_id.'">';
            $content .= '<input type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-sm pull-left" value="'.$language["delete"].'">';
            $content .= '</form>';
            $content .= '</td>';
            $content .= '</tr>';
            unset($class);
        }//loop ends here.
    } else { 
        $content = $language["cannot_i_user"];
    }   
    echo $content;
}//list_levels ends here.
```

I contacted the creator and was told. Right now subsystem use Jquery data tables to arrange data apply filters, and apply pages, so when using data tables of jquery we have to get all rows from table at once in your situation you have so many records that’s why you are getting issue. He wanted to charge me $20 to fix it.

Comment: "He wanted to change me $20 to fix it." sounds like a good deal to me.

Comment: I'd rather buy a new user management system then give him another $20 dollars to fix a flaw with script that I already bought.

Comment: Yeah... If you're manipulating 5400 records with jQuery, you're gonna have a bad time.

Comment: So, instead, you want us to fix it for you ... for free?

Comment: No wanted to see if anyone had any idea's, on how I could try to fix it.

Comment: If you really want to fix it yourself, do some research on pagination.

Comment: No, you're trying to save $20. Look, it's rude to come here and say, "Hey, this person wants $20 to fix MY problem, I don't want to pay him, so I want you to do it for free?"

Comment: Scripts you buy from places like Envato etc... are built to satisfy the masses. If you want customization, you should expect to pay extra

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yup, try taking the results in smaller sets one way or another. Write a function to get individual records ten or better still,one at a time, to start with, and take it from there.See how it scales up. That way your users can be sure of seeing something while you retrieve and process all the rest of the records.

Also if you don't know php, buying ready-made scripts is a pretty bad way to go about things. Build from the bottom up.

And keep your $20 for some decent coffee/beer, while you look for some basic tutes on php. Or get this book for a brilliant but gentle intro to the language - databases, paged result sets, logins, you name it:  [http://www.amazon.com/PHP-Solutions-Dynamic-Design-Made/dp/1430232498](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430232498)

As far as your script goes,

```
   $query = 'SELECT * from users ORDER by account_id ASC LIMIT 10';
```

is a good start, and then take it from there.

Or you could put the whole query + processing in a for loop, performing the ten-strong retrieve with each iteration of the loop.

Also, since we're on the subject of performance, this is a nice tute on variable interpolation vs concatenation (i.e. deals with how you build up your string/html).
 http://nikic.github.io/2012/01/09/Disproving-the-Single-Quotes-Performance-Myth.html

Remember in this instance that code readability is paramount while you get to grips with the language, so I'd go with the interpolated variables. That way you'll be able to see what's going on while you hack away at getting all those results from the database and working them into your page. Don't be daunted, php is a nice straightforward language once you take the plunge.

The other way would be to serve up a small result set when the user first loads the page/clicks to get the results, then gradually serve the rest via AJAX, ie without having to    reload the page, simply inserting subsequent elements into your division as and when they are ready. Here's a good AJAX tutorial to get you started:

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp

Comment: $10 for coffee, $10 for beer, then spend the night hacking the sh!t out of that script  :)

Comment: Will take a look at that, reading up on php jquery pagination now.

Comment: @ESG - did you try `set_time_limit(0);` ?

Comment: Ya I had, it will just run till you get a 504. Think my best option is reading up on some of this stuff, pagination looks like it would fix it.